# How to enforce compilation with a given JDK in Maven

Tags: java, maven, java-8, java-7

I am working in an enviroment with applications using different Java versions: 7, 8 and later.
The developers have thus installed several JDKs and each Maven pom.xml has indeed the correct `<source>` and `<target>` tags. However, sometimes the developers unadvertedly compile using a higher JDK. So they may include a Java 8 class like `java.time.LocalDate` in a Java 7 which will compile because it is able to resolve the import when compiling. But when the application is later moved to run on a JRE 7 it will fail because it is unable to find the Java 8 class.
It is possible to create a profile in the pom.xml like:

```
<profile>
  <id>compiler</id>
    <properties>
      <JAVA_1_4_HOME>C:\Program Files\Java\j2sdk1.4.2_09</JAVA_1_4_HOME>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

However, the location of the JDK varies per developer and I want a pom.xml which is common for everybody.

So the question is, **how to enforce Maven to use a given JDK version?** Not only the `<source>` and `<target>` but the JDK itself and in a generic way not tied to any given computer.

Comment: compile should fail if `maven.compiler.target` is set to 1.7 and using Java 8 features in your code

Comment: @MarcStröbel so I've thought myself, too. But if you have a JDK 8 compiler installed and maven.compiler.{source,target} are set to 1.7, the compilation still succeeds!

Comment: it's ok if you don't use Java 8 features in your code... the jdk version doesn't matter, the compiler output is 1.7 compatible

Comment: @MarcStröbel that's the thing, OP wants to enforce this to disallow the usage of JDK 8 features if source/target is set to 1.7

Comment: The problem is that production environment only has Java 7. Developer imports and uses a Java 8 class (even with <source> and <target> set to 1.7). Runs tests. Everything looks fine. Then the application is deployed and it fails at runtime because cannot resolve the Java 8 import.

Comment: i see... http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html. There are some hints at the bottom of the page, e.g. Animal Sniffer Maven Plugin to check used apis

Comment: @SergMTen does my answer now satisfies your needs?

Comment: Also note that toolchains allow for Maven knowing of multiple JDK's.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Initially I've thought that setting source/target to 1.7 for `maven-compiler-plugin` would be enough to fail the compilation but if you have a JDK 8 installed, the compilation succeeds(strange!).

What you really need is `maven-enforcer-plugin`. See the below configuration, I've put it to run on `validate` phase, which is just before `compile`:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-cli</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enforce</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <requireJavaVersion>
                                <version>[1.7,1.8)</version>
                            </requireJavaVersion>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Output:

```
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3:enforce (default-cli) @ compiler-demo ---
[WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireJavaVersion failed with message:
Detected JDK Version: 1.8.0-152 is not in the allowed range [1.7,1.8).
```

You can even set a custom message to make things clearer for your colleagues, e.g.

```
<rules>
  <requireJavaVersion>
    <version>[1.7,1.8)</version>
    <message>Project requires JDK 7</message>
  </requireJavaVersion>
</rules>
```

Output:

```
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3:enforce (default-cli) @ compiler-demo ---
[WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireJavaVersion failed with message:
Project requires JDK 7
```

Just for the sake of exploring the plugin's capabilities, I tried to see if it supports multiple version ranges. It does(running with a JDK 11 to try it out):

```xml
<requireJavaVersion>
    <version>[1.7,1.8),[9,10)</version>
</requireJavaVersion>
```

Output:

```
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3:enforce (default-cli) @ compiler-demo ---
[WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireJavaVersion failed with message:
Detected JDK Version: 11.0.1 is not in the allowed range [1.7,1.8),[9,10).
```

Comment: This detects the java version, not the javac version. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MENFORCER-368

Answer (score 0):

```
export JAVA_HOME=..... && mvn clean compile
```

That should ensure you're using the correct JDK

Comment: If I export a JDK 11, what would that solve? Nothing.